# Is there a way of only running unit tests in a single module using Eunit in Erlang/OTP?

Tags: erlang, eunit

I have a number of modules with unit tests. Is there a way of only running unit tests in a *single* module?

This is what the relevant section of the module looks like:

```
-export([ ..... ])
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").
...
...
...
first_test() ->
  ...
  ...

second_test() ->
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: rebar3 eunit docs on running tests: https://www.rebar3.org/docs/running-tests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eunit:test(yourmodule)` or `yourmodule:test()` should work.

Answer (score 7):

Run all tests in the module/suite (as iuriza's answer):

```
$ rebar3 eunit --module=mod1,mod2,mod3
```

Or you can also specify an individual test case (by function name):

```
$ rebar3 eunit --test=mod1:test1+test2,mod2:test1
```

References:

https://rebar3.org/docs/testing/eunit/

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `rebar3` you can use the `--module` option per their [Running Tests](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/running-tests) doc.

```
rebar3 eunit --module=your_module
```

If you have tons of modules, but only want to run tests for a few of them, you can separate the names with commas:

```
rebar3 eunit --module=first_module,second_module,third_module
```

The documentation has a lot of tips for limiting the tests run to a single application, file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
rebar clean eunit suite=your_module
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on the response from Adam Linberg, I did:

```
rebar3 as test shell
```

which makes possible to compile unit test files. Then you can type:

```
eunit:test(yourmodule)
```

or

```
yourmodule:test()
```